document.querySelector returning null after signing in on firebase but once site is refreshed it returns an element
my issue is that a document.querySelector returns null right after I signin on firebase, however after I refresh the page then it works and returns the proper element and makes the innerHTML work. To make the site efficient I want to get rid of the need to refresh to page to return something using innerHTML. Why is it doing this? on my index.html page I have the proper ID. this is my code on index.html using bulma as well
<div class="column is-half has-background-danger-light has-text-centered mr-3 my-3"             id="currentList">  
 <div class="content has-text-left" id="content"> 
   <table> 
      <thead> 
      <th>Item:</th> 
      <th>Price:</th>
      <th>Location:</th>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table class="table has-background-danger-light">
    <tbody id="list-content"></tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

here is the relevant java script that is causing the issue
    function showList() { 
        db.collection("listItem")
       .where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email)
       .get()
       .then((res) => { 
    let mydocs = res.docs; 
    let html = ""; 
   if (mydocs.length == 0) {
       r_e("list-content").innerHTML = "No items currently available"; return; 
    } 

    mydocs.forEach((d) => {
    
    html += `
    <tr class=" is-5 mt-3 subtitle" id="${d.id}" ><td>${
      d.data().productName
    }</td> <td>${d.data().price}</td> <td></td> <td>${
      d.data().productType
    }<button onclick="delete_doc('${
      d.id
    }')" class="has-background-warning-light is-small is-pulled-right">✓</button></td>`;
  });

  html += `</tr>`;
  console.log(r_e("list-content"));
  document.querySelector("#list-content").innerHTML = html;
});
} 

Here is the code where I call the function showList()
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    // check if there is current user
    if (user) {
        showList();

        signoutbtn.classList.remove("is-hidden");

        signinbtn.classList.add("is-hidden");

        r_e("email-nav").innerHTML += auth.currentUser.email;
    } else {
        // no user or signed out 
        // hide signout button 
        signoutbtn.classList.add("is-hidden");
        // show the signup button
        signupbtn.classList.remove("is-hidden");

        signinbtn.classList.remove("is-hidden");
        content.innerHTML = `<p class="has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">You have be signed in to see content</p>`;
        r_e("list-form").innerHTML = `<p class="has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">You have be signed in to see content</p>`;

        r_e("email-nav").innerHTML = "";
    }
});

I want it show up right after the user signs in.
this is the website right after i sign in without refreshing the page. Nothing comes up in the middle content part
this is the page after I refresh and the list shows up
